# mysqli result - brackets around url-get parameters

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following code.

```
public function load($data)
{
    $result = Database::select("SELECT * FROM `table1` ORDER BY `id` LIMIT ? OFFSET ? ;", $data, "ii");

    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $this->_data['data'][]  = $row;
        }
    }
}

public static function select($sql, $data, $types)
{
    try
    {
        self::connect();
        $stmt = self::$connection->prepare($sql);
        if ($stmt === false)
        {
            echo mysqli_error(self::$connection);
        }
        call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', array_merge (array($stmt, $types), makeValuesToReferences($data)));

        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->get_result();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Table1 have a text field which stores text and urls.

**The Problem**
This urls, stored in datafield named text, have get parameters which get concatenated with brackets. 
A print_r looks like this

```
[id] => 23
[text] => Some text <a href=/search.html?q=something else
[param1] => 29   <== param1 is a parameter of <a href=/search.html?q=something...
[param2] => 9>word</a>more text <== param2 is a parameter of <a href=/search.html?q=something...
```

Normally the field content of [text] looks like

```
Some text <a href='/search.html?q=something+else&param1=25&param2=1 '>word</a> more text
```

**The Question**

Why are this get parameters concatenated with brackets?

**EDIT**

This is, what i await

```
Some text <a href='/search.html?q=something+else&param1=25&param2=1 '>word</a> more text
```

This is, what i get

```
Some text <a href='/search.html?q=something else [param1] => 25 [param2] => 1' word</a>more text
```

Comment: So? What is your question?

Comment: Please specify problem.

Comment: are you talking about [id], [text] and so on? This is the way print_r represents array keys.

Comment: @WaldsonPatricio the data that comes from table1 can only have to datafields, because there are not more. [id], [text].

Comment: edited again. forget the print_r.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. The calling script have had the function `parse_str`. So the urls from the database tablefield "text" was converted to `[key] => value` pairs.

Thanks for your time ;-)